# Как в Java считать из консоли ввод чисел и вывести их в консоль в обратном порядке?

Tags: java

Как реализовать в Java ввод чисел из консоли и их вывод на консоль в обратном порядке?

Пример:

Ввод с клавиатуры:

```
1
2
10
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
10
2
1
```

Comment: используйте стек.

Comment: Записать числа в массив и вывести в обратном порядке????

Comment: для начала покажите, что получилось у вас, тогда будет понятно, в чем проблема

Answer (score 1):

**Вот**:

```
// Создаем Сканер
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
// Считываем строку и разделяем пробелами
String[] inputs = s.nextLine().split(" ");

// Идем по элементам массива в обратном порядке
for (int i = inputs.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    // Выводим значение
    System.out.print(inputs[i] + " ");
}

// Закрываем Сканер
s.close();
```

**или** *(с использованием foreach)*:

```
// Создаем Сканер
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
// Считываем строку и разделяем пробелами
String[] inputs = s.nextLine().split(" ");
// Создаем переменную для нового текста 
String newString = "";
// Идем по элементам массива в обратном порядке
for (String string : inputs) {
    // Прибавляем элемент к началу нового текста 
    newString = string + " " + newString;
}
// Печатаем новый текст
System.out.println(newString);
// Закрываем Сканер
s.close();
```