# Как вывести цифры числа в java?

Tags: java

Нужна помощь...
Задача следующая:
Нужно ввести любое число, например 123 и нужно вывести на экран 1, 2, 3 через цикл while
Пишу программу - выводит 3 2 1. но не 1 2 3....

Весь день ломаю голову непонимаю...
Помгите....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExersiseChapter15 {
    
    public static Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Введите число: ");
        int a = reader.nextInt();
        int b = 0;

        while (a > 0) {
            b = a % 10;
            System.out.print(b + " ");
            a /= 10;        
        }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите свой код

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExersiseChapter15 {
    
    public static Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Введите число: ");
        int a = reader.nextInt();
        int b = 0;

        while (a > 0) {
            b = a % 10;
            System.out.print(b + " ");
            a /= 10;        
        }                 
    }
}

Comment: Поместите код в тело вопроса нажав "Править" под ним

Comment: Я бы перевёл число в строку и выводил бы символы строки и не парился бы со взятием остатка

Comment: вы,ребятки, видимо с одних курсов : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229987/java-%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: Сереж, я пока не умею в строку переводить и по условиям задачника нужно это сделать через цикл while... 
Я изучаю java всего лишь месяц...

Comment: @Дмитрий и как ответ по ссылке противоречит тому, что я написал?

Comment: @Drseal90 никак, даже наоборот: весь курс на стеке в один день задает один и тот же далеко не оригинальный вопрос, который является домашним заданием. вроде как в одном экземпляре достаточно...

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();
while (a > 0) {
    b = a % 10;
    digits.add(b);
    a /= 10;        
}           
for (int i = digits.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(digits.get(i).toString() + " ");
}
```

Comment: Игорь не хватает запятых

Comment: вывести на экран 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 1):

Вот так попробуйте

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExersiseChapter15 {

public static Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Введите число: ");
    int a = reader.nextInt();
    int b = 0;
    String result ="";

    while (a > 0) {
        b = a % 10;
        result = b.toString() + result !="" ? ", "+result: result;
        a /= 10;        
    }  
   System.out.print(result);                
}
}
```

Comment: Есть ли какой то готовый метод который 3 2 1 превращает в 1 2 3?

Comment: Есть только он по ходу обучения. reverse можно посмотреть. Но в вашем примере вы выводить остаток. А нужно сформировать результат потом выводить

Comment: Потому что вы вычисляет остаток от деления. Их нужно для начала все получить затем собрать как нужно и выводить.

Answer (score 1):

Если обязательно надо использовать цикл while:

```
String[] array;
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    array = String.valueOf(sc.nextInt()).split("");
}
int i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
    System.out.print(array[i++] + ",");
}
```

Если while не обязателен, то можно inline:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(sc.nextInt()).split("")).forEach(e -> System.out.print(e + ", "));
}
```

Как убрать последнюю запятую и пробел - придумайте сами. К принципиальному решению задачи это не относится.